# how to store values and retrieve it when the orientation changes?

Tags: android, orientation

I have checked many posts, and as per that I have done coding for the orientation change. When orientation changes, the problem is I am not able to retrieve the entered values inside TextViews. Can anyone plz tell where did I go wrong?

Coding:

In manifest file for the corresponding activity I added:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

In activity, I added the following methods:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);
    //Initialized the widgets
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //have written separate layout files for portrait and landscape
    setContentView(R.layout.home_screen); 
    //Initialized the widgets again
    retrieveSavedState();  //sets the TextViews again
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState(); //save the TextView values
}

@Override 
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) { 
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); 
    saveState();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    retrieveSavedState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() 
{
    final MyDataObject data = collectMyLoadedData();
    return data;
}
```

the above method can be used to save any object to save data...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MyDataObject data = (MyDataObject) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (data == null) {
        data = loadMyData();
    }
    ...
}
```

and u can retreive that object in the `onCreate()` which will we called when orientation changes.. after reading data from that object you can use it where ever you want..

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

other mechanisms are also there but this is the best way for my knowledge.. you can also use shared preferences to store and retrieve data...

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Comment: The above methods didn't help me out!! I used SharedPreference at last. It worked with that...